# RMI - who invoked the method

Tags: java, rmi

is there a way to know what server/client invoked a method on the server?

Problem:
I have a completely connected graph of server, and when a command comes in from a client on one of the server nodes, I forward it to the rest of the server nodes on the graph. I want to only forward the commands if and only if it's coming from a client and not another server.

Comment: Can you make the "is client?" part of the request?

Comment: I could do that, but I'm wondering if there is an easier way

Answer (score 2):

Rather than trying to find out the client, why not provide two implementations of the server object? One that forwards requests, and one that doesn't? I would subclass the forwarding version from the non-forwarding version, and register them under different names.

However, it seems to me that you really want a messaging architecture rather than RMI between the servers.

Comment: what is "message architecture" ?

Comment: Using an asynchronous messaging framework to notify the servers that a particular operation has occurred.